# Get the last element in JSON file

Tags: json, linux, bash, parsing, jq

I have this JSON file:

```
{
      "system.timestamp": "{system.timestamp}",
      "error.state": "{error.state}",
      "system.timestamp": "{system.timestamp}",
      "error.state": "{error.state}",
       "system.timestamp": "{system.timestamp}",
      "error.state": "{error.state}",
      "error.content": "{custom.error.content}"
}
```

I would like to get only the last object of the JSON file as I need to check that in every case, the last object is `error.content`. Attached part of code is just a sample file, every file that will be generated in reality will contain at least around 40 to 50 objects, so in every case I need to check that the last object is `error.content`.

I have calculated the length by using `jq '. | length'`. How do I do it using the `jq` command in Linux?

Note: it's a plain JSON file without any arrays.

Comment: That's not JSON... well, technically I guess you can say it is. But having an object with _many_ duplicate keys is practically worthless. Any self respecting JSON parser will just remove/overwrite the duplicated properties and will likely keep that last anyway. You're way better off fixing it than trying to work with it in that state.

Answer (score 1):

Objects with duplicate keys can be handled in jq using the --stream option, e.g.:

```
$ jq -s --stream '.[length-2] | { (.[0][0]): (.[1]) }' input.json
{
  "error.content": "{custom.error.content}"
}
```

For large files, the following would probably be better as it avoids "slurping" the input file:

```
$ jq 'first(tostream) | {(.[0][0]): .[1]} ' input.json
```